# Find PDF of a stochastic process

Tags: probability-or-statistics, stochastic-calculus

I consider the following Ito process

```
β = 2;
Ne = 100;
γ = 1;
process = 
  ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]s[
       t] == -(β/Ne) s[t] i[t] \[DifferentialD]t - 
      Sqrt[β/Ne s[t] i[t]] \[DifferentialD]n1[
         t], \[DifferentialD]i[
       t] == (β/Ne s[t] - γ) i[t] \[DifferentialD]t + 
      Sqrt[β/Ne s[t] i[t]] \[DifferentialD]n1[t] - 
      Sqrt[γ i[t]] \[DifferentialD]n2[t]}, {s[t], 
    i[t]}, {{s, i}, {90, 10}}, 
   t, {n1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
    n2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]}];
```

Is there a way to find the PDF of `s` and `i` or its discrete values for some discretization of `t`?

**Update**
@Sjoerd Smit suggested to use the code

```
proc = ItoProcess[{1, 2}, {x, 0}, t];
rf = RandomFunction[proc, {0, 10}, 1000];
Plot[
  PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[rf["SliceData", 2]], x],
  {x, -5, 10}
]
```

which works perfectly for some systems, but not on mine.

Then, @Josh Bishop pointed out that since I deal with a vector process, I should use

```
rf = RandomFunction[proc, {0., 5., 0.01}];
Plot3D[PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[rf["SliceData", 2]], {s, i}], {s, 42, 49}, {i, 19, 27}]
```

However, the output is as follows, i.e., PDF is 0 everywhere.

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer. Hopefully everything is clear :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For simple processes this can be done by using the function `PDF`:

```
proc = ItoProcess[{\[Mu], \[Sigma]}, {x, 0}, t];
PDF[proc[t], x]
```

> E^(-((x - t [Mu])^2/(2 t [Sigma]^2)))/(Sqrt[2 [Pi]] Sqrt[
>    t [Sigma]^2])

If that doesn't work for your process, it's most likely that the analytic PDF simply cannot be computed. In that case you're pretty much down to sampling the process with `RandomFunction` to get a Monte Carlo approximation of the PDF. You can use a function like `KernelMixtureDistribution` or `SmoothKernelDistribution` to create a smooth PDF from the samples at a given time `t`.

For example, this is how to plot the approximate PDF at `t = 2` for a simple process:

```
proc = ItoProcess[{1, 2}, {x, 0}, t];
rf = RandomFunction[proc, {0, 10}, 1000];
Plot[
  PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[rf["SliceData", 2]], x],
  {x, -5, 10}
]
```

> [image]

**edit**

Ah, I see the problem with this attempt. In the line

```
rf = RandomFunction[proc, {0., 5., 0.01}];
```

the process is sampled only once. You need multiple paths to approximate the PDF at a given point in time, so let's do 1000 samples (I'm going to assume that the process has already been defined as in the question):

```
rf = RandomFunction[process, {0, 5, 0.01}, 1000];
```

Let's say we want to inspect the PDF at `t = 2.`. Check the dimensions of the slice data:

```
t1 = 2.;
Dimensions[rf["SliceData", t1]]
```

> {1000, 2}

First compute the domain of the PDF and pre-compute the distribution:

```
{{mins, maxs}, {mini, maxi}} = CoordinateBounds[rf["SliceData", t1]]
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[rf["SliceData", t1]]
```

To plot the distribution, it is usually a good idea to keep the number of plot points in check by setting values for `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` (the number of times Mathematica tries to refine the plot). My personal opinion is also that `ContourPlot` is almost always easier to interpret than `Plot3D` for these sort of things:

```
ContourPlot[
 PDF[dist, {s, i}],
 {s, mins, maxs},
 {i, mini, maxi},
 PlotPoints -> 20,
 MaxRecursion -> 1,
 PlotRange -> All
]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, Sjoerd. I tried PDF, but it doesn't seem to work for my system or I do something wrong. If you have time, I would appreciate if you could demonstrate some uses of the functions you mention in your answer. Thank you!

Comment: I tried `SmoothKernelDistribution`, but it results in an empty plot.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan If you made some new attempts based on my code, could you update the question with your new code? I hope I have time to give it some more attention later in the week, but right now I'm a bit strapped for time unfortunately.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan You have a vector process so you'll need to use `Plot3D`. For example, you can try `rf = RandomFunction[proc, {0., 5., 0.01}]; Plot3D[PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[rf["SliceData", 2]], {s, i}], {s, 
  42, 49}, {i, 19, 27}]`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that the output should be a surface. I tried `Plot3D` and the PDF seems to be 0 everywhere. I will update the post.

Comment: @SjoerdSmith Thank you very much for your time. Everything is clear! By the way, is there a way to have PDF of `s` and `i` separately?

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan Yes, there is. You can use `MarginalDistribution` to convert the distribution into one of its maginals. E.g., `PDF[MarginalDistribution[dist, 1], s]` gives you the marginal over `s` and `PDF[MarginalDistribution[dist, 2], i]` the one over `i`.

Comment: Also, I noticed that the paths tend to start yielding complex values for larger values of `t`. You may want to think about what that means for the process, since it looks like something is ill-defined (unless `s` and `i` are in fact quantities that are allowed to be complex-valued, of course).

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that and no, they are to be real-valued. Moreover, `s + i = 1` at any point `t`. I also get some errors when I increase the number of paths.